# Euler #4 with bigger domain

Tags: haskell, ghc

Consider the modified Euler problem #4 -- "Find the maximum palindromic number which is a product of two numbers between 100 and 9999."

```
rev :: Int -> Int
rev x = rev' x 0

rev' :: Int -> Int -> Int
rev' n r
    | n == 0 = r
    | otherwise = rev' (n `div` 10) (r * 10 + n `mod` 10)

pali :: Int -> Bool
pali x = x == rev x

main :: IO ()
main = print . maximum $ [ x*y | x <- nums, y <- nums, pali (x*y)]
    where
        nums = [9999,9998..100]
```

- This Haskell solution using `-O2` and `ghc 7.4.1` takes about **18
  seconds**.
- The similar `C` solution takes **0.1 second**.

So Haskell is 180 times
   slower. What's wrong with my solution? I assume that this type of
   problems Haskell solves pretty well.

**Appendix - analogue C solution:**

```
#define A   100
#define B   9999
int ispali(int n)
{
    int n0=n, k=0;
    while (n>0) {
        k = 10*k + n%10;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return n0 == k;
}
int main(void)
{
    int max = 0;
    for (int i=B; i>=A; i--)
        for (int j=B; j>=A; j--) {
            if (i*j > max && ispali(i*j))
                max = i*j;      }
    printf("%d\n", max);
}
```

Comment: How similar is the C solution?

Comment: @larsmans I appended the C solution.

Comment: Why not simply `head` instead of `maximum`? The list is sorted in descending order, so the first element is the maximum.

Comment: @RafaelCaetano, the list is absolutely not in descending order. There are two loops nestedt. Test it with [9,8..1] to convince yourself.

Comment: @NicolasDudebout, you're right of course, I was careless in my comment. Though I suppose there's a nice way of traversing the list of products in descending order...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> The similar C solution

That is a common misconception.

## Lists are not loops!

And using lists to emulate loops has performance implications unless the compiler is able to eliminate the list from the code.

If you want to compare apples to apples, write the Haskell structure more or less equivalent to a loop, a tail recursive worker (with strict accumulator, though often the compiler is smart enough to figure out the strictness by itself).

Now let's take a more detailed look. For comparison, the C, compiled with gcc -O3, takes ~0.08 seconds here, the original Haskell, compiled with ghc -O2 takes ~20.3 seconds, with ghc -O2 -fllvm ~19.9 seconds. Pretty terrible.

One mistake in the original code is to use `div` and `mod`. The C code uses the equivalent of `quot` and `rem`, which map to the machine division instructions and are faster than `div` and `mod`. For positive arguments, the semantics are the same, so whenever you know that the arguments are always non-negative, never use `div` and `mod`.

Changing that, the running time becomes ~15.4 seconds when compiling with the native code generator, and ~2.9 seconds when compiling with the LLVM backend.

The difference is due to the fact that even the machine division operations are quite slow, and LLVM replaces the division/remainder with a multiply-and-shift operation. Doing the same by hand for the native backend (actually, a slightly better replacement taking advantage of the fact that I know the arguments will always be non-negative) brings its time down to ~2.2 seconds.

We're getting closer, but are still a far cry from the C.

That is due to the lists. The code still builds a list of palindromes (and traverses a list of `Int`s for the two factors).

Since lists cannot contain unboxed elements, that means there is a lot of boxing and unboxing going on in the code, that takes time.

So let us eliminate the lists, and take a look at the result of translating the C to Haskell:

```
module Main (main) where

a :: Int
a = 100

b :: Int
b = 9999

ispali :: Int -> Bool
ispali n = go n 0
  where
    go 0 acc = acc == n
    go m acc = go (m `quot` 10) (acc * 10 + (m `rem` 10))

maxpal :: Int
maxpal = go 0 b
  where
    go mx i
        | i < a = mx
        | otherwise = go (inner mx b) (i-1)
          where
            inner m j
                | j < a = m
                | p > m && ispali p = inner p (j-1)
                | otherwise = inner m (j-1)
                  where
                    p = i*j

main :: IO ()
main = print maxpal
```

The nested loop is translated to two nested worker functions, we use an accumulator to store the largest palindrome found so far. Compiled with ghc -O2, that runs in ~0.18 seconds, with ghc -O2 -fllvm it runs in ~0.14 seconds (yes, LLVM is better at optimising loops than the native code generator).

Still not quite there, but a factor of about 2 isn't too bad.

Maybe some find the following where the loop is abstracted out more readable, the generated core is for all intents and purposes identical (modulo a switch of argument order), and the performance of course the same:

```
module Main (main) where

a :: Int
a = 100

b :: Int
b = 9999

ispali :: Int -> Bool
ispali n = go n 0
  where
    go 0 acc = acc == n
    go m acc = go (m `quot` 10) (acc * 10 + (m `rem` 10))

downto :: Int -> Int -> a -> (a -> Int -> a) -> a
downto high low acc fun = go high acc
  where
    go i acc
        | i < low   = acc
        | otherwise = go (i-1) (fun acc i)

maxpal :: Int
maxpal = downto b a 0 $ \m i ->
            downto b a m $ \mx j ->
                let p = i*j
                in if mx < p && ispali p then p else mx

main :: IO ()
main = print maxpal
```

Comment: A factor of two speed difference isn't bad, but the readability difference really hurts.

Comment: @DanielWagner You're looking at the wrong stuff. Take a look at the generated core, that's much more readable without the lists ;) But I wouldn't mind if GHC became better at eliminating lists either. Unfortunately, I have no idea how that could be done.

Comment: Even if I were to accept that you might read core instead of source Haskell, you're really going to try to argue that the core is more readable than the C? From what I can see, the C code is both more readable and faster than any of the functional versions -- I think that's pretty unusual and a bit painful.

Comment: No, I wasn't quite serious with the first part (the `;)` unfortunately went on the next line). But of course I read the core too if I'm interested in performance. I don't find it _that_ unusual that C is more readable for such tasks that map very well to C's concepts and not so well to Haskell's. And the speed difference, well, it's not so easy to beat a mature C compiler at its bread-and-butter stuff, we have to live with that for a few years to come.

Comment: @DanielFischer Well, maybe the right answer is the bread-and-butter part of your comment :) Answer accepted.

Comment: @DanielWagner Maybe Haskell could use syntactic sugar for C-style for loops that translates it into the equivalent fold and strict accumulator.

Comment: if you use `ispali p && p > m` as OP's code is doing, then there is only a negligible speedup. Yes, with functional loops as in your answer it is easy to swap the order of tests; not so with the list comprehension code. Larsmans' list-based code gives it ~7x speedup; *then* going loops gives it another ~9x. But with lists it is easier to *correct the algorithm*: `head $ filter pali $ map negate $ foldt union [] [ [ (- (x*y)) | y <- nums] | x <- nums]` runs 4 times  faster than the fun_loops-based code, for me.

Comment: correction to my previous comment: 4x faster at `nums=4000 to 100`, 14.5x faster at `nums=10000 to 100`. I.e. the complexity is much improved (obviously).

Comment: @WillNess If you change the algorithm to short-cut, you can do **much** better than that with the loops. Just change the lower bound of the inner loop to ``max a $ m `quot` i``, or, if you want to be a bit cleverer, to ``max i $ m `quot` i`` and you're good for a couple more digits (complexity of O(digits*10^digits) vs. O(digits*10^(2*digits)) of the original).

Comment: I get no speed difference b/ween list-based version and the short-cutting loops. The shortcut on inner loop (counting down on `j=i,i-1...`) is two-fold: either when `i*j <= m` or `i*j` is palindromic. The starting `m` is 0, so at first smaller `m`s can be found. The list version is from the above comment corrected as: `... | y <- [x,x-1..a] | x <- nums]`. The merging works in "perpendicular" direction to the fun-loops version ("by columns" vs. "by rows"), and is guaranteed to find the correct `m` value *first*. My point was ease of code tweaking, for me it's w/ lists, but that's subjective.

Answer (score 2):

@axblount is at least partly right; the following modification makes the program run almost three times as fast as the original:

```
maxPalindrome = foldl f 0
  where f a x | x > a && pali x = x
              | otherwise       = a

main :: IO ()
main = print . maxPalindrome $ [x * y | x <- nums, y <- nums]
  where nums = [9999,9998..100]
```

That still leaves a factor 60 slowdown, though.

Comment: BTW, see http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Foldr_Foldl_Foldl' -- `foldl'` is generally preferable to `foldl`

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: I tried `foldl'` as well, it wasn't any faster. Feel free to edit it into the answer, though.

Comment: are you using `ghc -O2` ? Wonder why it's still so slow compared to what I wrote.

Comment: The three times as fast comes from foldl' (or foldl) with -O2

Answer (score 1):

<s>Haskell may be storing that entire list [ x*y | x <- nums, y <- nums, pali (x*y)] where as the C solution calculates the maximum on the fly. I'm not sure about this.</s>

Also the C solution will only calculate ispali if the product beats the previous maximum. I would bet Haskell calculates are palindrome products regardless of whether x*y is a possible max.

Comment: The list shouldn't be stored, that defeats the purpose of laziness. The second part might be part of the problem, though.

Comment: The second one is true, the first one is not, and I'd upvote this answer if first part weren't there.

Comment: @larsmans To find the maximum it will have to evaluate every element of the list. so it will have to store a lazy representation of every element of the list.

Comment: Haskell solution allocates 4 MB on the heap.

Comment: I've edited so more people could upvote. :) You've nailed one of the reasons for the OP's Haskell code inefficiency. larsmans's code (based on your answer) runs ~7 times faster then OP's. Then, using loops as in Daniel's answer gives it another ~9x speedup on my box.

Comment: @WillNess Why thank you. I was going to let it stand, warts and all, but strike through works just as well.

Answer (score 1):

This is more true to what the C code is doing:

```
maxpali :: [Int] -> Int
maxpali xs = go xs 0
  where
    go [] m     = m
    go (x:xs) m = if x > m && pali(x) then go xs x else go xs m

main :: IO()
main = print . maxpali $ [ x*y | x <- nums, y <- nums ]
  where nums = [9999,9998..100]
```

On my box this takes 2 seconds vs .5 for the C version.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you are having a branch prediction problem. In the C code, you have two nested loops and as soon as a palindrome is seen in the inner loop, the rest of the inner loop will be skipped very fast.

The way you feed this list of products instead of the nested loops I am not sure that ghc is doing any of this prediction.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to write this is to use *two* folds, instead of one fold over the flattened list:

```hs
-- foldl g0 0 [x*y | x<-[b-1,b-2..a], y<-[b-1,b-2..a], pali(x*y)]      (A)
-- foldl g1 0 [x*y | x<-[b-1,b-2..a], y<-[b-1,b-2..a]]                 (B)
-- foldl g2 0 [ [x*y | y<-[b-1,b-2..a]] | x<-[b-1,b-2..a]]             (C)

maxpal b a = foldl f1 0 [b-1,b-2..a]                              --   (D)
  where
    f1 m x = foldl f2 m [b-1,b-2..a]
      where
        f2 m y | p>m && pali p = p
               | otherwise     = m  
           where p = x*y

main = print $ maxpal 10000 100
```

Seems to run much faster than `(B)` (as in larsmans's answer), too (*only 3x - 4x slower* then the following loops-based code). Fusing `foldl` and `enumFromThenTo` definitions gets us the "functional loops" code (as in DanielFischer's answer),

```
maxpal_loops b a = f (b-1) 0                                      --   (E)
  where               
    f x m | x < a     = m 
          | otherwise = g (b-1) m 
      where
        g y m | y < a         = f (x-1) m
              | p>m && pali p = g (y-1) p 
              | otherwise     = g (y-1) m
           where p = x*y
```

The `(C)` variant is very suggestive of further *algorithmic* improvements (that's outside the scope of the original Q of course) that exploit the hidden order in the lists, destroyed by the flattening:

```
{- foldl g2 0 [ [x*y | y<-[b-1,b-2..a]] | x<-[b-1,b-2..a]]             (C)
   foldl g2 0 [ [x*y | y<-[x,  x-1..a]] | x<-[b-1,b-2..a]]             (C1)
   foldl g0 0 [ safehead 0 . filter pali $
                [x*y | y<-[x,  x-1..a]] | x<-[b-1,b-2..a]]             (C2)
   fst $ until ... (\(m,s)-> (max m .
                safehead 0 . filter pali . takeWhile (> m) $
                                                   head s, tail s))          
           (0,[ [x*y | y<-[x,  x-1..a]] | x<-[b-1,b-2..a]])            (C3)
   safehead 0 $ filter pali $ mergeAllDescending
              [ [x*y | y<-[x,  x-1..a]] | x<-[b-1,b-2..a]]             (C4)
-}
```

`(C3)` can stop as soon as the head `x*y` in a sub-list is smaller than the currently found maximum. It is what short-cutting functional loops code could achieve, but not `(C4)`, which is guaranteed to find the maximal palindromic number *first*. Plus, for list-based code its algorithmic nature is more visually apparent, IMO.